# How to change the learning rate of specific layer from the solver prototxt (CAFFE)

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

Anybody knows how to change the learning rate `lr_mult` of a specific layer in CAFFE from the solver prototxt? I know there's `base_lr`, however I would like to target the rate of a specific layer, and doing it from the solver instead of the network prototxt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Every layer that requiers learning (i.e convultional, fully-connected, etc.) has a specific `lr_mult` parameter that can be controlled specifically for that layer. `lr_mult` is a "multiplier on the global learning rate for this parameter."

Simply define or change the `lr_mult` for your layer in `train_val.prototxt`.

This is useful for fine-tuning, where you might want to have increased learning rate only for the new layer.

For more info check the caffe [fine-tuning](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html) tutorial. (Note: it is a bit outdated and the deprecated term `blobs_lr` is used there instead of `lr_mult`)

**EDIT**: To my best knowledge it is not possible to define a layer-specific learning rate from the `solver.prototxt`. Hence, assuming the `solver.prototxt` limitation is not strict, I suggest a different method to achieve the same result.

Comment: the OP *specifically* asked about a method to change `lr_mult` from the *solver.prototxt* and NOT from the train_val.prototxt. So how does your post answer the question here?

Comment: @shai I think an answer that says "the solver.prototxt is not the place to make architecture-level decisions; here's how to do it correctly" is a valid answer. The question is almost an X-Y problem; without motivating why you would need to make this decision at the solver level, I can only assume OP isn't doing something sensible here